# Angular access component providers in effects

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am using Angular 7 and ngrx/store I have some component with very complicated logic. It injects different services at component level: `providers: [Service1, Service2]`. Also, I have an action `UpdateComponentPresentation` and in effects, I want to achieve something like this:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  updatePresentation$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UpdateComponentPresentation),
    map((action) => {
      const someComponentId = action.payload.id;
      const service1 = getComponentServiceInstanceById(id);
      this.service.rerender();
    })
  );
```

So is it possible to get somehow into effects instance of the component service? It is important that services should be injected at the component level because I can have multiple components at the same time on the page. And in that services, I have many internal data related to the current component instance.

Comment: Can you explain why are you calling on a service 'rerender'?

Comment: Because this service is responsible for rendering component